# Magento & Google Checkout & Track Conversions

Tags: magento, google-analytics, google-checkout

I'm running an online store on Magento.  I have Google Checkout as a Payment method.  The problem is if someone pays using it they don't always return to the site so it throws my Google Analytics conversion rates off.  Is there a way to pass this information to analytics when the people don't return to the site after the transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento has built-in support for sending data about Google Checkout process to Google Analytics. Implementation of this functionality is done according to 
http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/checkout/developer/checkout_analytics_integration.html

You should see all the data (e.g. pages visited) and conversions from GC normally. The customer is not required to return to your shop.

**Step1: no GC conversions in GA**

Allow up to 24h delay before the conversion data will appear in GA.

**Step 2: After 24h you still don't see GC conversions in GA**

Make sure you've enabled Google Analytics in Magento and setup it properly, because GC module in Magento sends data to GA only if it's activated and working fine.

**Step 3: If steps 1-2 are done, everything works and GA is activated, but GC conversions still not visible in GA**

Make sure that your design theme includes all necessary GC & GA code as made in base/default scheme. You can temporarily enable default/modern theme to check that original core Magento code works fine and then check the differences between your design theme and Magento core theme

**Step 4: you've done steps 1-2-3, but no conversions are present in GA**

Hire a Magento professional to find the source of a problem. In such a case this problem cannot be solved remotely.

Comment: Does [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/171/fooman-google-analytics-plus) help that in any way?

Comment: It adds some advance features. But GA tracking is enabled even without this extension.

Answer (score 0):

The only data that comes back from Paypal after the customer has paid would be the IPN callback that notifies Magento of the payment. If you wanted to hook into this, you would need to find a direct URL to notify GA of the conversion and to periodically monitor the database for IPN notifications so that you could invoke that URL.